# SQL - using an alias in a where clause

Tags: where-clause, clause

I am having trouble using an alias in my SQL:

```
SELECT
    InvoiceDate,
    BillingAddress,
    BillingCity,
    Total,
    CASE
        WHEN Total < 2.00 THEN 'Baseline Purchase'
        WHEN Total BETWEEN 2.00 AND 6.99 THEN 'Low Purchase'
        WHEN Total BETWEEN 7.00 AND 15.00 THEN 'Target Purchase'
        ELSE 'Top Performer'
    END AS PurchaseType

FROM
    invoices

WHERE 
    PurchaseType = 'Top Performer'

ORDER BY
    BillingCity
```

I get the following error:
Invalid column name 'PurchaseType'.

Comment: Assuming that you use MySQL: you cannot use column aliases in a WHERE clause. You need to repeat the whole CASE ... END code. You might try to use HAVING which allows for column aliases. Basically – very simplified – the WHERE clause might be executed before the columns results are built. HAVING, GROUP BY, and ORDER BY are executed after the columns results are built.

Comment: Hi, I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Can you show my code with the update that needs to be done?

Comment: Replace _WHERE PurchaseType = 'Top Performer'_ with _WHERE CASE WHEN Total < 2.00 THEN 'Baseline Purchase' WHEN Total BETWEEN 2.00 AND 6.99 THEN 'Low Purchase' WHEN Total BETWEEN 7.00 AND 15.00 THEN 'Target Purchase' ELSE 'Top Performer' END_.

Comment: CASE
        WHEN Total < 2.00 THEN 'Baseline Purchase'
        WHEN Total BETWEEN 2.00 AND 6.99 THEN 'Low Purchase'
        WHEN Total BETWEEN 7.00 AND 15.00 THEN 'Target Purchase'
        ELSE 'Top Performer'

END AS 
 PurchaseType

FROM 
 invoices

WHERE CASE WHEN Total < 2.00 THEN 'Baseline Purchase' 
 WHEN Total BETWEEN 2.00 AND 6.99 THEN 'Low Purchase' 
 WHEN Total BETWEEN 7.00 AND 15.00 THEN 'Target Purchase' 
 ELSE 'Top Performer' END

ORDER BY 
 BillingCity

An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'ORDER'.

Comment: FROM 
 invoices

WHERE
CASE WHEN Total < 2.00 THEN 'Baseline Purchase' 
WHEN Total BETWEEN 2.00 AND 6.99 THEN 'Low Purchase' 
WHEN Total BETWEEN 7.00 AND 15.00 THEN 'Target Purchase' ELSE 'Top Performer' END

ORDER BY 
 BillingCity       I get the following error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 34
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.